# Why doesn't my ListView display the TextView on older devices if each item is a CardView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cardview

Below is my `Listview` item layout. I fail to understand why my list is not showing the text view on some devices. I'm guessing it may have something to do with smaller screen sizes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_speciality"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Abcd"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try using a linear layout.

Comment: @JCodes13 can you pls tell me why? I am totally confused why the same code is not working on some devices. i have put my layout in res/layout folder and no crash is seen.

Comment: It may depend on your ic_speciality resource width. But if you set a fixed width to your `ImageView`, that won't happen in any device.

Answer (score 0):

When setting an `ImageView` with `layout_width` attribute at `"wrap_content"`, you are telling the `ImageView` to have the width of the resource you are using. Your resource probably has a large width dimension, and in smaller screens, it occupies all the screen width. If you use a fixed width value (like 25dp) on your `ImageView` you'll avoid this issue.